# Why is code reading html from wrong site?

Tags: html, url, web-scraping, http-post, rvest

I am using code read_html("https://www.globenewswire.com/Search/NewsSearch?exchange=Otc%20Markets") to acquire certain information from that webpage.

But the problem is, is that the html code is reading from the link below, which is the link you must get to/click on before getting to the above link. The is a problem because the links on this page are from stock exchanges that I cannot use, where as the above link contains link/articles that I need/can use.

https://www.globenewswire.com/NewsRoom

Why is it reading from the wrong url? My thoughts are that it needs a post request for info after the "?" in the first url

Comment: What language are you using to do that ?

Comment: I’m using the rvest package in r

Comment: I know python is probably better for this, but I’m more comfortable with R

Comment: what do you click on in the first page to get to the second?

Comment: So the second link, the one in blue is the page where you can specify which industry, stock exchange, etc. you want your articles to come from. I clicked the OTC markets box, and from there the url is the one I have in the read_html(). I am pretty sure it has something to do with the ?, I tried using 3%F  in place of that which was supposed to counter that but it did not work.

Comment: 3%F is an actual question in the url, whereas the ? Separates the beginning of the url and after is the query. I need to read html from url that has query!

Comment: Just construct it. Take the market name you want and urlencode it then concatenate to base string  "https://www.globenewswire.com/Search/NewsSearch?exchange=" + URLencode("Otc Markets") where URLencode is the appropriate R function to encode. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/URLencode

Comment: @QHarr: URLencode is not the problem.

Comment: Ok. I though OP wanted to generate that URL. My bad.

Comment: For what the page actually does you can use the dev tools network tab to see the post request used initially for update.

Comment: @QHarr No. It's not that simple either. It sends requests with some kind of token but you can't really imitate it. This website is difficult to scrape.

Comment: Probably should try RSelenium.

Comment: I haven't tried scraping but from what I observed in browser 1) It has protection incapsula 2) It indeed passes a variety of sessional info from the initial GET including session cookies and OP would need to see whether these can be captured client side (e.g. with HTMLSession, RSelenium).